# How to install Commons Codec?

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons, codec

How can I install the commons codec? I've downloaded but I've searched online and couldn't find an answer to this. I want to use the Base64 encoder and decoder.

Also 1 more question, if my code uses this codec, will other users that try to use my program require it too? or is it just compiling?

Thanks

Comment: As with every other 3rd party library, just put it in the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, if some one else uses your code, and if your code internally uses the Base64, then just compiling won't help, you will have to supply the Base64 jar with your code as you code at runtime depends on the Base64 code.

To your first question, in the project itself you can add the Base64 jar, and then try to execute the jar in a standalone mode. There is a way to add the jar inside the jar, and then your code will use that jar internally.

Comment: umm i didnt jar my thing though, all i got is the client.java and the class of the client. I just compile and run through command prompt, I'm still testing the program so until I finish I cant jar it.

Should I put it in the same folder as the client.java?

Comment: then in that case you can try adding the Base64 jar in the classpath while executing the program from the command prompt, if not added, then the code will expect the Base64, then then will fail.

`java -cp <<full path of Base64.jar>> <<Your Java Code>>`